# Replacement of correlated query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with name orders:

```
id  id_o  value  date
 1   1     400   2014-09-30 
 2   1     300   2014-09-30
 3   1     200   2014-09-30 
 4   2     100   2014-09-30  
 5   2     200   2014-09-30
 6   3     50    2014-09-29
 7   3     100   2014-09-29
 8   4     300   2014-09-29
 9   5     600   2014-09-28
```

I need select every order grouped by id_o with sum(value)< 700 and from this selected table i need display data grouped by datum. 
I use multiple select:

```
select date, sum(mno) as mn 
from (
   select date,sum(value) as 'mno' 
   from orders 
   group by id_o 
   having sum(value)<700
) table_alias 
group by date
```

This is result:

```
date            mn
2014-09-30      300
2014-09-29      450
2014-09-28      600
```

Is there any possibility to replace or to simplify this correlated query?

Comment: Your query is fine (except for the single quotes around the column alias).  Your terminology is wrong.  That is not a correlated subquery.

Comment: Note that your subquery selects date but groups id_o. MySQL allows this - but it IS a little weird!

Comment: Ok, so this isn't correlated query but multiple select. Is there any way to replace this multiple select with something more simple , for example simple query? Or is it ok in terms of database load?

Comment: It's called a "derived table" and there is nothing wrong with using it. The group by  in the the derived table is indeed invalid (standard) SQL and would be rejected by every other DBMS though. See here for details: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 1):

Your inner query is invalid. It groups by `id_o`, but selects by `date`. In order to solve this, add an additional column to the inner queries grouping (assuming date is always the same for every `id_o`). You can enable strong checking by enabling the `sql_mode`'s `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. Full example in [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/396c8/9).

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(mno) AS mn 
FROM (
    SELECT
        id_o,
        date,
        SUM(value) AS mno
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY
        id_o,
        date
    HAVING
        SUM(value) < 700
) totalPerOrder
GROUP BY date
```

MySQL allows this type of queries, but it's not common to do so. Consider the following data:

```
id  id_o  value  date
 1   1     400   2014-09-29 
 2   1     300   2014-09-30
 3   1     200   2014-09-30
```

What `date`(s) would `SELECT date, SUM(value) FROM orders GROUP BY id_o` return? It could be the first, last, average, most common one, but better make it explicit. Any other DBMS wouldn't let you execute this query.

Other than that, I would rename some of the columns to be more expressive. `mn`, `mn_o` and `id_o` are examples of this. Also `value` describes nothing, anything can be a value. Even the `date` field could have been called `value`. The query itself seems fine (take care if possibly missing indexes though).

Comment: Why is inner select invalid? But it works. Column id_o is not important in the next processing, it is used only in the clause "group by". Why did you use multiple group by id_o, date? I tried this, but result was the same as with "group by id_o". Is there any way to replace this multiple select with something more simple? I read that similar multiple selects very load the database server.

Comment: I've added an example in my answer, I hope it helps but if it doesn't, let me know.